# Mail sender address is not getting updated

Tags: email, mailx

I'm trying to send email, but I constantly get wrong sender email address.

**OS details:**

```
NAME="Ubuntu" VERSION="18.04.5 LTS (Bionic Beaver)"  
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian  
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS"  
VERSION_ID="18.04" 
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/" 
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"  
PRIVACY POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
VERSION_CODENAME=bionic 
UBUNTU_CODENAME=bionic
```

**Note:** we have installed `mail` and `ssmtp`. I only have mailhub configured in the `ssmtp.conf` file.

From address supposed to be `xyz@company.com` but it is coming as `xyz@guid`.

The commands tried so far:

```
echo "Hello there" | mail -s "Test Mail" -r sender@company.com mail-to@receiver@company.com 
echo "Hello there" | mail -s "Test Mail" -r mail-from@sender@company.com mail-to@receiver@company.com 
echo "Hello there" | mail -s "Test Mail" -r 'First Last <sender@company.com>' receiver@company.com 
echo "Hello there" | mail -s "Test Mail" -aFrom:'First Last <sender@company.com>' receiver@company.com 
echo "Hello there" | mail -s "Test Mail"  receiver@company.com -aFrom:sender@company.com
echo "Hello there" | mail -s "Test Mail"  -aFrom:IROL-Admin\<sender@company.com\> receiver@company.com
```

Comment: Please [edit] and copy and paste the system details, rather than a screenshot of text. A screenshot is not text searchable.

Comment: Addresses of the obsolete form `mail-to@receiver@company.com` are unlikely to make it through any meaningful email system

Comment: we are using 'mail' & 'ssmtp'. I only have mailhub configured in the ssmtp.conf file.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to explain there that you're using ssmtp. Also add what you can from the configuration file (redact where necessary). Also show what errors you're getting

Answer (score 1):

I got it working with the below SSMTP.Conf

```
root=sender@company.com
mailhub=mailhost.company.com:25
FromLineOverride=YES
```